# How to Generate stub for SOAP wsdl using python

Tags: python, wsdl

I am using SOAP library PySimpleSOAP for client and server webservice interfaces.

We are using mediamind api

```
campaign_client =  SoapClient(wsdl="https://platform.mediamind.com/Eyeblaster.MediaMind.API/CampaignService.svc?wsdl"
                              ,trace = False)
```

I tryed to call 
data = campaign_client.GetContact(ContactID=1,UserSecurityToken=token)

getting error

```
Error:%s Invalid Args Structure. Errors: [u"Argument key UserSecurityToken not in parameter. parameter: {u'ContactID': <type 'int'>}, args: {'ContactID': 1, 'UserSecurityToken': u'5a547757-e2e7-45e4-9ec7-4748f995ec62'}"]
```

To remove this error I learned that I need to generate stub for SOAP wsdl.

Comment: Maybe a little bit more info?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling it the wrong way. The correct way would be:

```
data = campaign_client.GetContact({'ContactID': 1,'UserSecurityToken':token})
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply..now.. I am alraeady autheniticated still Getting below Error:%s s:Security.Authentication.AuthKeyInvalid: The security token is invalid; please authenticate using the AuthenticationService->AuthenticateClient(user,password,appKey)

Comment: No..I have done  client.ClientLogin and got authentication tocken

Comment: The error says you need to use `AuthenticationService->AuthenticateClient`. Did you do that?

Comment: Maybe you should have  a try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76445/discussion-between-sagar-and-skyline75489).